# Change Firebase Cloud Message account

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have my android app running firebase cloud message using `uat@gmail.com`. and now, i need to change the administration to production account `bbb@mycompany.com`

what i have done, using `bbb@mycompany.com` to create new project and generate a new `google-services.json` and replace existing `google-services.json` i created with `aaa@gmail.com`

using android studio connect to firebase and show 
**Firebase: A config file "D:\xxx\xxx\google-services.json" was found, but it indicates a project ID "xxx-1vv" that you dont appear to have access to. Request access or delete the file in order to proceed with the connection process.**

anyone could help??

Comment: Are you talking about the email address of the Google account that owns the Firebase project that you use for messaging?

Comment: yes, and i would like to change to another account for administration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transfer ownership of a Cloud (Firebase) product without having to change the way your users user the project.  Please [read this for details](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access?hl=en&visit_id=636718134997666292-887953149&rd=1).  Note that all Firebase projects are also Cloud projects, so anything you do in the Cloud console applies to Firebase.